# Vector of object pointers and virtual methods

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

First of all sorry if i've chosen wrong title, but wasn't sure how to name it.

Code structure first:

```
//== 1st file ==
class A {
private:
    int x;
public:
    int GetX() { return x; }
};

//== 2nd file ==
class B {
private:
    A ob1;
public:
    virtual A & GetARef() { return ob1; }
};

class C : public B {
private:
    A ob2;
public:
    A & GetARef() { return ob2; }
};

class D : public B {
public:
    // something else w/e
};


//== 3rd file ==
class E {
private:
    std::map <int,C> m;
public:
    C* GetCPtr(int idx) { return &m[idx]; }
};

//== 4th file ==
void foo(E & E_Obj) {
    std::vector <B*> v;
    v.push_back(E_Obj.GetCPtr(0));
    v.push_back(/*some pointer to D class*/);
    Boo(v); // FORGOT TO ADD IT ! Sorry
};

//== 5th file ==
void Boo(std::vector <B*> & v) {
    std::cout << v[0]->GetARef().GetX(); // returns B::ob1 's x instead of C::ob2 's x.
};
```

As wrote in comments, Boo gets wrong 'x'. I just wonder if it's because that pointers go 'out of scope' or I misdesigned something wrong. How to fix that, so I can get proper x (C::ob2 's one).

Sorry for kinda strange class names etc., but orginal code is much longer, so I tried to show the situation only.

@edit
Forgot to add that in Foo() it returns what i expect - C::ob2 's x.

Comment: what are you passing to `Boo` ?

Comment: If you worry about getting out of scope, you could try adding some logging in C's destructor.

Comment: @Medinoc or use smart ptrs.

Comment: How is the vector passed to `Boo` being populated?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the most important code line, which anserws your questions. Vector passed to Boo() is populated and passed in Foo(). Please check updated code. Sorry :(

Comment: Instead of reducing your code to a non-compilable snippet (incomplete and with typos) for posting on StackOverflow, you should rather first create a new project on _your_ computer, bake a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), try debug it a bit, and _then_ post the _real_ minimal compilable code (and maybe you will already have found the problem only by doing the first part). Help us to help you.

Comment: After simplifying and correcting some typos, I'm not seeing a problem: http://ideone.com/DYYQy9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not leaving reply in comments, but I decided it's worth whole post. Also sorry for such late reply. I've spent whole day and night digging slowly through code, since you've proved that my coding was fine (except few typos in example code, sorry for that). Practically after rewriting code letter after letter I finally found the troublemaker somewhere I would normally never look for. My co-worker while sorting some things was switching not the pointers in related vector but their content.

Something like that

```
vector <E*> v;
// ...
*v[i] = ...
```

instead of

```
v[i] = ...
```

After fixing that, it indeed works as intented. Thanks for your help and clearing things out. Also sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: This is correctly answer, because it concludes the question. You should accept it (yes, you _can_ accept your own answers).

Answer (score 0):

This is the essence of what you are doing

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{
        const int b = 0;
        public:
        virtual const int& getInt(){
                return b;
        }   
};
class LeafOverriding : public Base{
        const int l = 1;
        public:
        virtual const int& getInt(){
                return l;
        }   
};
class Leaf : public Base{
};

int main(){
        cout << Leaf().getInt() << '\t' << LeafOverriding().getInt() << endl;
}
```

and it has no problems (i.e. it does indeed output 0 1). I would say that your snippet -- which does not compile, btw -- does not represent the real code.

I'm so lazy I forced you to compile it with C++11 support, because of `const int b = 0` and `const int l = 1` :)